# zooming in one subplot and then display it in another subplot

Tags: image, user-interface, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I have created a GUI which has 2 subplots.The first one display original image.

How can i do when i want to **zoom in** first subplot and then display it in second subplot? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by copying the data from the first subplot to the second and setting the axis limits. Here's an example that doesn't use a GUI but should work the same way:

```
figure
% create two subplots
ax1 = subplot(2,1,1);
ax2 = subplot(2,1,2);

% display some data in the first subplot
axes(ax1);
imagesc(spiral(10));

% get the range of the axes in the first subplot
xLim1 = get(ax1, 'XLim');
yLim1 = get(ax1, 'YLim');

% Ask the user to zoom in. Instead of pressing 
% enter, there could be a button to push in 
% a GUI
reply = input('Zoom in and press enter');

% Get the new, zoomed in axes
zoomedXLim = get(ax1, 'XLim');
zoomedYLim = get(ax1, 'YLim');

% get the data from the first axis and display
% it in the second axis.
data = getimage(ax1);
axes(ax2)
imagesc(data)

% set the second axis to the zoomed range
set(ax2, 'XLim', zoomedXLim)
set(ax2, 'YLim', zoomedYLim)
title('zoomed image')

% return the first axis to its original range.
set(ax1, 'XLim', xLim1)
set(ax1, 'YLim', yLim1)
axes(ax1)
title('original image')
```

The resulting figure will look something like this:

[image: original image and zoomed image]